# Unable to boot Ubuntu from external USB hard drive, kernel panic

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, usb-storage, kernel-panic

The same system has booted fine in the past. Now, when I try to boot, it fails. In recovery mode, it ends in:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

The GRUB bootloader is on my internal drive, but the system has booted just fine from the external one in the past. The power/in-use LED on the external drive turns off in the end, like power was cut from it. I tried turning secure boot off, legacy boot on in the motherboard BIOS, but as expected it did not help. How could I rescue the system to be bootable? My OS on the main drive is Windows 10.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)?

Comment: The error message is explicit. There are error in the root file system. Boot a live session and correct them.

Comment: On some PC's (particularly HP's), I've found, a USB drive can be damaged after being used to boot. In most cases, the external drive is not *physically* harmed, and a new Linux image can be installed on the USB. You might need to manually change boot order, but your internal disk should be OK.